# Plot points over contour - Matplotlib / Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot some points over a contour using Matplotlib.

I have scalar field from which I want to plot the contour.
However, my **ndarray** has a dimension 0 x 20, but my real space varies from -4 to 4.

I can plot this contour using this piece of code:

```
x, y = numpy.mgrid[-4:4:20*1j, -4:4:20*1j]

# Draw the scalar field level curves
cs = plt.contour(scalar_field, extent=[-4, 4, -4, 4])
plt.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=10)
```

The problem is 'cause I have to plot some points over this plot, and this points are obtained using the **ndarray**, i.e., I get points varying as this array dimension.

I tried to plot these points using this code:

```
def plot_singularities(x_dim, y_dim, steps, scalar_field, min_points, max_points, file_path):
    """
    :param x_dim : the x dimension of the scalar field
    :param y_dim : the y dimension of the scalar field
    :param steps : the discretization of the scalar field
    :param file_path : the path to save the data
    :param scalar_field : the scalar_field to be plot
    :param min_points : a set (x, y) of min points of the scalar field
    :param max_points : a set (x, y) of max points of the scalar field
    """
    min_points_x = min_points[0]
    min_points_y = min_points[1]
    max_points_x = max_points[0]
    max_points_y = max_points[1]

    plt.figure()

    x, y = numpy.mgrid[-x_dim:x_dim:steps*1j, -y_dim:y_dim:steps*1j]

    # Draw the scalar field level curves
    cs = plt.contour(scalar_field, extent=[-x_dim, x_dim, -y_dim, y_dim])
    plt.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=10)

    # Draw the min points
    plt.plot(min_points_x, min_points_y, 'ro')

    # Draw the max points
    plt.plot(max_points_x, max_points_y, 'bo')

    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png', dpi=100)
    plt.close()
```

But I got this image:

[image]

Which is not correct.

If I change this line:

```
cs = plt.contour(scalar_field, extent=[-x_dim, x_dim, -y_dim, y_dim])
```

For that one:

```
cs = plt.contour(scalar_field)
```

[image]

I get the desired behavior, but the extents doesn't show my real data space, but the **ndarray** dimension.

At last, if I don't plot these points (comment the plot() lines), I can the extents that I want:

[image]

But I have to plot the points.
Both data are in the same space. 
But the **contour()** function allows me to specify the grid.
I could found a manner to do this when plotting the points.

How can I properly set the extents?

Comment: It would help to know what you were expecting. What should the "data space" be? Are both the points and contour incorrect, or just the contour?

Comment: If you look to the second image, it is correct (the plots). However is showing the extents as the ndarray dimensions (from 0 to 20). I would like to show it varying from an my data space (with the center in 0,0 and varying from -4 to 4). I call my "data space" as an analogy to the CG concepts to image space (ndarray) and world space (my real data space).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't provide `x` and `y` data corresponding to the scalar field, `contour` uses integer values up to the size of the array. That is why the axes are displaying the dimension of the array. The parameters `extent` should give the minimum and maximum `x` and `y` values; I assume this is what you mean by "data space." So the call to `contour` would be:

```
contour(scalar_field,extent=[-4,4,-4,4])
```

This can be reproduced by specifying `x` and `y` data:

```
contour(numpy.linspace(-4,4,20),numpy.linspace(-4,4,20),scalar_field)
```

Then the contour looks exactly as in your first plot. I assume the reason this is incorrect because the min and max points are not in the right places. Based on the info you gave, this is because `min_points` and `max_points` which you pass to your function are *indices* to the array `scalar_field`, so they correspond to integers, not the actual `x` and `y` values. Try to use these indices to access the `x` and `y` points by defining:

```
x=numpy.linspace(-4,4,20)
y=numpy.linspace(-4,4,20)
```

For example, if you have a min point of `(0,1)`, it would correspond to `(x[0], y[1])`. I think a similar thing can be done with the `mgrid`, but I've never used that myself.

Comment: Thank you! As I have just right now written for @Ajean, I know that these were indices and that this was the problem (sorry if I couldn't express myself in a good way). I was looking for a clever way to do this conversion in Matplolib/Python. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You want to plot both the contour and the points in the real data space, yes?  `plt.contour` will take x and y values associated with the 2d array you have, and will plot on axes correctly.

```
xvals = -x_dim:x_dim:step  # I'm not sure about these ... but you get the idea
yvals = -y_dim:y_dim_step
plt.contour(xvals, yvals, scalar_field)
```

Comment: If I just do this, I get the first image, which do not respect the space that I want when I plot the points.

Comment: Are you sure that the points you are plotting are in the right space, then?  It looks like you're plotting actual values with one thing and indices with the other.

Comment: They are both in the same space. I change my extent as a parameter when plotting the contour, but I don't know how to do this when plotting the points.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding here ... when you plot points, they are (x,y) values, and plot will put them right where they are, no matter what. A 2D array to be displayed (via contour) has no inherent (x,y) positions associated with it, which is why you need to specify them (either by extent or by the xvals and yvals above).  If your x-y points being plotted by plot are truly in the x_dim/y_dim space, (-4 to 4), this will work.  It looks like they are *indices*.

Comment: Notice that the 4 max points are at 0-0,0-19,19-0,19-19, and your array is length 20.

Comment: Yes, it is really that. I'm wondering if I have to do a space conversion manually, induce by induce, or if there is some Matplotlib/Python "magic", as defining a grid and the points been adjusted, I dont'know.